# Strange behavior of error function series expansion at infinity

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

Evaluating

```
Normal[Series[1/ (1 + xi Erf[xi]), {xi, ∞, 2}]]
Normal[Series[1/( xi (1/xi + Erf[xi])), {xi, ∞, 2}]]
```

gives

```
1/(1 + E^-xi^2 (-(1/Sqrt[π]) + 1/(2 Sqrt[π] xi^2)) + xi)
1/((1 + 1/xi - E^-xi^2/(Sqrt[π] xi)) xi)
```

Why are they different in order? This problem also occurs when other error function related function such as `DawsonF` was used.

## Update

In fact the above is just trying to give a minimal demo to my real problem which is

```
zf[xi_] := -2 DawsonF[xi] + I Sqrt[π] Exp[-xi^2];
(*zf[xi_]:=zff[xi];*)
(*zf[xi_]:=bigArgExpansion[xi];*)
xi[kpara_, Ω_] := -((Ω τ)/(kpara R0 ϵni)) Sqrt[bθ/2];
N1[Ω_] := 1 + (1 - 3/2 ηi)/(Ω τ);
N2[Ω_] := ηi/(Ω τ);
A1[kpara_, Ω_] := N1[Ω] D1[kpara, Ω] + N2[Ω] (D1[kpara, Ω] + D2[kpara, Ω]);
D1[kpara_, Ω_] := Inactive[xi][kpara, Ω] zf[Inactive[xi][kpara, Ω]];
D2[kpara_, Ω_] := Inactive[xi][kpara, Ω]^2 (1 + D1[kpara, Ω]) + D1[kpara, Ω];
D5[kpara_, Ω_] := -1 - 2 Inactive[xi][kpara, Ω]^2 (1 + D1[kpara, Ω]);
D6[kpara_, Ω_] := -(5/2) - Inactive[xi][kpara, Ω]^2 (3 + 2 D1[kpara, Ω]) - 
   2 Inactive[xi][kpara, Ω]^4 (1 + D1[kpara, Ω]);


D3[kpara_, Ω_] := -(1 + D1[kpara, Ω] + D5[kpara, Ω]);
D4[kpara_, Ω_] := -D2[kpara, Ω] - (Inactive[xi][kpara, Ω]^2 D5[kpara, Ω]);


G2du[z_, Ω_] := (((N1[Ω] D3[z/(q R0), Ω] + N2[Ω] D4[z/(q R0), Ω]) Inactive[xi][z/(q R0), Ω]^2)/(τ));

G2[z_, Ω_] := (G2du[z, Ω]/(A1[z/(q R0), Ω]));
G2O4[z_, Ω_] = 
  Activate[
   Normal[Series[G2[z, Ω], {Inactive[xi][z/(q R0), Ω], I ∞, 2}]]];
G2O4s[z_, Ω_] = 
  Activate[
   Normal[Series[
     Simplify[
      G2[z, Ω]], {Inactive[xi][z/(
       q R0), Ω], I ∞, 2}]]];
q = 1.4; shat = 0.776; τ = 1.0; ϵni = 1/2.22; ηi = 3.114; 
ϵne := ϵni; ϵTi := ϵni/ηi; ϵTe := ϵTi; ηe := ηi; bθ = 0.335^2; R0 = 1;

Plot[Re[G2O4[z, 1]], {z, -0.1, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Re[G2O4s[z, 1]], {z, -0.1, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Re[Activate[G2[z, 1]]], {z, -0.1, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Re[Activate[Simplify[G2[z, 1]]]], {z, -0.1, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I was expecting that the four plots would be the same.

Comment: This looks like  bug to me. If you simplify the input before passing it to Series, you get same result for both cases. So the input is the same, but the output can not be shown to be the same. V 14. But both outputs is zero at infinity.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hry0e.png)

Comment: Yes, In fact I have another strange example using DawsonF function where Series and Simplify give even more confusing results `zf[xi_] := -2 DawsonF[xi] + I Sqrt[\[Pi]] Exp[-xi^2];
Normal[Series[1/ (1 + xi zf[xi]), {xi, I \[Infinity], 2}]]
Normal[Series[Simplify[1/ (1 + xi zf[xi])], {xi, I \[Infinity], 2}]]`. and the result reads `3 + 3/xi^2 - 2 xi^2,  -2 xi^2`. This problem seems related to the error function. Maybe there can be a workaround, just expand it to higher order and expand the output again since It seems that the difference is in a higher order.@Nasser

Comment: You might also want to report this to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Sure,Thanks.@Nasser

Comment: Don't see any problem here:`Limit[Normal[Series[1/(1 + xi Erf[xi]), {xi, \[Infinity], 2}]] -
  Normal[Series[1/(xi (1/xi + Erf[xi])), {xi, \[Infinity], 2}]], 
 xi -> Infinity]` results in `0`. Don't make a big thing from this.

Comment: The same issue with `zf[xi]`. Both `Normal[Series[1/ (1 + xi zf[xi]), {xi, I \[Infinity], 2}]]` and `Normal[Series[Simplify[1/ (1 + xi zf[xi])], {xi, I \[Infinity], 2}]]` approach `Infinity` as `xi` tends to `I*Infinity` and the difference approaches `3`.

Comment: Pls check the update @user64494

Comment: @ssskkkky: Sorry, you use  expansions at `I \[Infinity]` and draw plots around `0`.

Comment: Yes,But the expansion is about `Inactive[xi][kpara, Ω]:=-((Ω τ)/(kpara R0 ϵni)) Sqrt[bθ/2]` so in fact `kpara=1/(I \Infinity)`

Comment: @ssskkkky: Please pay your attention to `G2O4[z_, Ω_] = 
  Activate[
   Normal[Series[G2[z, Ω], {Inactive[xi][z/(q R0), Ω], I ∞, 2}]]];` in your code.